# Are there any other solutions to finding matrices that produce the desired result?

Tags: linear-algebra

How many 3 x 3 matrices $A$ can you find such that

$$
A
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
xy \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

for all choices of x, y, and z?

My solution to this is solving these equations:

$ax + by + cz = xy$

$dx + ey + fz = 0$

$gx + hy + iz = 0$

For the first equation it looks like we can get $xy$ via setting $a=0$, $b=x$, and $c=0$ or by setting $a=y$, $b=0$, and $c=0$. For the other two equations, we must have all $0$ for $d$ to $i$ to get an answer of $0$.

So the solution is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & x & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix}
y & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Does this look correct? Did I go about solving it the right way?

Comment: If the entries of $A$ are allowed to depending on $x,y,z$, there will be other possibilities.  If the entries of $A$ are *not* allowed to depend on $x,y,z$, there are no possible solutions.

Comment: But here $A$ depends on the vector! So one can not say that it is good for any vector. Note that multiplication with a matrix is a linear transformation.

Comment: So A shouldn't (is not allowed to?) to depend on the x, y, z vector?

Comment: By definition of a matrix it can't. What you are talking about is a function that associates a matrix to each $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^{3}$, that is not a matrix.